# Resolve database error in CodeIgniter and SQL Server database in live

Tags: php, sql-server, database, codeigniter, sql-server-2008

We are working codeigniter application with SQL Server database. In local everything working fine. But in live server it was showing following error

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings

And this is my config files.

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'SDI-SQLPWV01.sdi.local',
    'port' =>   1433,
    'username' => 'sdi\svc_epay',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'epaystub',
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

How to resolve this ?

Comment: Please don't use images for error messages when text would be much clearer.

Comment: Ok . This is the error message am getting "Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings." .

Comment: [edit] it into your question - and remove the image.

Answer (score 1):

You need to confirm your server credentials,
Host, Username, Password, Port

You can also try/confirm that your credentials are working using the following code

```
<?php

/* Connect to database using driver invocation */

try {
    $serverName = "yourservername";  
    $database = "yourdatabasename";  
    $conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$serverName;Database=$database", "username" , "password" );

     echo "connected successfully";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
     echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

It will help you troubleshoot connection problems.